# asp.net mobile app with jquery, how to show errors

Tags: jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I have a asp.net mvc4 app with jquery mobile UI, but after install it for producion it show me this error:

[image: Error launched from jquery]

All i need is see the real error.

I'm was trying adding

```
<customErrors mode="On"/>
```

To web.config, But this message is the only thing I could see.

How can i do to  disable this option on jquery?

NOTE: I'm using IIS8 on windows 8 machine, my .net framework is 4.

Comment: I'm not certain I understand. You've turned customErrors on in the web.config? If so, is it STILL on?

Comment: Yes , i turned it on and still is on. But I get the same message "Error loading page". I'll try with turning it Off and same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

jQuery mobile will detect the error and simply let you know there was an error.

If you use the developer tools on your browser and go to the network tab, you can see what the server returns on each request. This way, if you turn off customErrors, the server will return the detailed error information.

Answer (score 1):

Use the FireBug Add-on for Mozilla Firefox or the Developer Tools available in Google Chrome to see the actual response sent back by your HTML request. I would hazard a guess that your use of JQuery on the front end is swallowing the actual error and sanitizing the message displayed.